# Best practice with request authentication with time-stamping and async clients

Tags: authentication, asynchronous, go

I have a restful api written in Go.  I want to authenticate each request.  To do so, the server and the client share a secret.

To authenticate a GET request to `/foo/bar/`, the client add a nonce parameter with a timestamp to the url, `/foo/bar/?nonce=13899932199128265`, and then add the hmac of data with the secret to the url.  It gives something like `/foo/bar/?nonce=13899932199128265&hmac=hd7nd7s9s702j`

To verify the validity of an incoming request, the server verify that no requests from the client arrived after the time stamp and that the hmac is valide.

I believe it is a common way to authenticate requests.  For instance, mtgox uses a similar process.

The problem that I have is that my client will likely require a list of urls [url1, ... urln] at the same time.  In that case, nothing guarantee that the first request sent by the client will arrived first to the server.  Indeed, any permutation of the requests will result in 403 errors.

My first question is simple: is that a real problem?  Is it likely that request order will change during transport?

Second, is it entirely to the client to verify no 403 errors happen?

Is there better way to do?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, it is a real problem you will encounter. What you can do is to allow a maximum of N out of order request (I chose 5 I think when implementing this), and keep some sort of list of the last request ids received from the client, to make sure no request is replayed within that window.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer would your consider it be bad practice to discard the time nonce on GET but use it on POST (and other verbs)?  That is a solution that I think about right now.

Comment: It depends on your needs really. I usually build APIs that act the same for GET and post, but I do set different authentication levels for different calls obviously.

Comment: What if you relax the timing requirements and allow the time stamp in client requests to be in, say, 1 minute around the server's time? This will still have brute-forcing a password for crafting a replay attack pretty much infeasible while providing for flocks of unordered requests.

Comment: I fact I do not want to force the client to use a real time stamp.  A integer that increments at each requests should be enough.  That is the technique against reply attack.

As a solution, I will separate my api in two security levels.  The low security level will not require time stamp.  The hight yes.  In my case, the separation is will be the used verb.  But this is only because it makes sense in my api structure